# How to get Complete word's sub string with a fix width in pixel

Tags: php, css

I have a fixed div to display the string.
I want to display the sub string with most possible complete words, that would most fit in my div.

I used `strlen()` but it make too much difference in width size
i.e. too much difference in 
"`AAAAAAAA`" and "`iiiiiiii`"

Please help me to out from this prob.

For eg: there are two string:
1: My name is abhay and I am posting on stackoverflow.
2: I hope I will get my solution over here 100%.
Now I have a fix space to display these strings, and if string length exceeded the available length I need to display the max possible complete words with three dot (...)

I have wrote code to get the complete words with max 30 character for each string, but the problem is some strings shows very narrow and some wide because of difference in length of character.
eg: My name abhay and I am posting..
    I hope I will get my solution..

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with CSS, so I've removed the tag...

Comment: use a monospaced font...?

Comment: I readded [tag:css] tag as this can be solved by `CSS`, even easier than with `PHP`.

Comment: @lelloman, I can not change font because it will impact my design.

Answer (score 0):

Use `white-space: nowrap;` with `overflow: hidden;` on div.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wNxk9/) example.

Comment: Thamks! But my problem is that I can do this with css it self because I need to display the complete string of words.